# How to count all children records for a has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Having the following models

```
class Release
  has_many :sprints
end

class Sprint
  has_many :tasks
  belongs_to :release
end

class Task
  belongs_to :sprint
end
```

How can I count all the `tasks` for an specific `release`?

I tried this but it performs two queries and doesn't seem very efficient:

```
def total_task_count
  release = Release.find(1)
  Task.where(sprint_id: release.sprints.pluck(:id)).count
end
```

What's a better way of counting all children associations in a child association?

Also, If I want to do this in a list view:

```
@releases.each do |release|
  <%= release.total_tasks_count %>
end
```

How can I perform a single query instead of one per release?

Comment: You need to set up a has many through relationship

Answer (score 4):

Add a `has_many through` relationship.  See the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

in the `release` model, add:

```
has_many :tasks, through: :sprints
```

Then you can do

```
@releases.each do |release|
  <%= release.tasks.count %>
end
```

Comment: Cool, I missed the part where I can use has_many through that way. However, that `each` loop executes a `count(*)` query for each release and I'd like to avoid that, can you point me to a better direction?

Answer (score 2):

As John Feltz mentioned, you can use `has_many through` on the `Release` model.

To run a all queries at once, you can also use `.includes`:

`Release.includes(:task).find(#{id_here})`

When you call `release.tasks.count`, it will already have the data, so it will not run another query. See more about `includes` in the [API Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes).

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
def total_task_count
  Task.joins(:sprints).merge(Sprint.where(release_id: 1)).count
end
```